# Using CMD window, get the most recent filename for each folder of the current directory

Tags: cmd

How can I use the cmd window to get the name of the most recent file in each folder in the current directory?

I feel like this is either a multistep process of commands or a one-liner beyond my current knowledge.

I am only familiar with using "one off" commands from the command line such as 
`dir /b /o:n /ad > folderlist.txt`, so any reference to doing more complicated cmd line tasks would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to iterate over the list of directories and over the list of files in each directories. This can be done using a `FOR` loop. See `FOR /?` for more details.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

PUSHD "C:\the directory\of interest"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d IN (`DIR /B /A:D .`) DO (
    DIR /B /A:-D %%d >NUL 2>&1
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /B /A:-D /O:D %%d`) DO (
            SET LASTFILE=%%f
        )
        ECHO %%d\!LASTFILE!
    )
)

POPD
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as long as it is in the parent directory.

Comment: The question said "in the current directory" so I took it at face value. If this is an answer, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: I do have a question on what should be added to make it work by setting the path for parent directory, so i can keep the batch file in a separate folder. Since, the "." lists the directory of the batch file and replacing with the full path of the folder I wanna use doesnt work, because then using "/B" gives only the folder/file name and not the full path reference. (a little unsure of how to concatenate in BATCH; and given it is a work computer i can't use programming languages i actually know!)

Comment: I added a PUSHD and POPD. PUSHD will put you (CD) into the directory specified. POPD will go back to whatever the current working directory was before the PUSHD. It works like a stack.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Sorry I didn't fully qualify what I actually had to do. I was testing on folders I created, but found out I didn't have write permissions to the folder I needed to read.